# Adding user via admin panel in android studio with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to ask for your help with something that eating my brain out since I am new at Firebase and android studio. I created this attendance app but only the admin can log into the system then as the admin he has the ability to add students and teachers so that they can have access to the system when they want to log in the system. but once I add a teacher he cannot log in the system. the system saying incorrect username and password while the credentials are all well-typed. is there a way to give access to a user without creating the sign-up page. I am using firebase as the database. here is my code for adding a teacher

```
public class FacultyAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar addFacTool;
private EditText facName, facEmail, facPhone, facID, facAddress;
private Spinner facSpinner;
private String[] designList;
private String selectDesign;
private Button addFacBtn;
private String intentMode, intentFac;
private DatabaseReference facReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_faculty_add);

    addFacTool = findViewById(R.id.toolAdd);
    setSupportActionBar(addFacTool);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intentFac = intent.getStringExtra("FACULTY");
    intentMode = intent.getStringExtra("MODE");

    facName = findViewById(R.id.txtLName);
    facEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtLEmail);
    facAddress = findViewById(R.id.txtLAddress);
    facPhone = findViewById(R.id.txtLPhone);
    facID = findViewById(R.id.txtLID);
    addFacBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnLSubmit);
    facSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spnDes);

    designList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.designation);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(FacultyAddActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, designList);
    facSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    facSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectDesign = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    addFacBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addFaculty();
        }
    });
}

private void addFaculty() {
    String name = facName.getText().toString();
    String email = facEmail.getText().toString();
    String address = facAddress.getText().toString();
    String phone = facPhone.getText().toString();
    String ID = facID.getText().toString();

    if (name.isEmpty()){
        facName.setError("Enter lecturer name");
        facName.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (email.isEmpty()){
        facEmail.setError("Enter lecturer email");
        facEmail.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        facEmail.setError("Enter lecturer email");
        facEmail.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (address.isEmpty()){
        facAddress.setError("Enter lecturer address");
        facAddress.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (phone.isEmpty()){
        facPhone.setError("Enter lecturer phone number");
        facPhone.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (selectDesign.isEmpty() && selectDesign.equals("Select Designation")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select Designation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (ID.isEmpty()){
        facID.setError("Enter lecturer ID");
        facID.requestFocus();
    }
    else{
        facReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("Lecturer");
        String key = facReference.push().getKey();

        FacultyConstructor facultyConstructor = new FacultyConstructor(ID, name, intentFac, selectDesign, phone, email, address, "123456", intentMode);
        facReference.child(key).setValue(facultyConstructor).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lecturer added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600** (six hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: will do, so its best to ask step by step. thanks man